# Мультфільм - питоме чи запозичене слово

Tags: етимологія, росіянізм

СУМ-11

> [Мультфільм](http://sum.in.ua/s/muljtfiljm)  у, чол. Скорочення: мультиплікаційний фільм.

Зрозуміло, що слова *мультиплікаційний* і *фільм* — запозичені. Але звідки взялася їхня скорочена комбінація — *мультфільм*: чи була вона утворена безпосередньо в українській мові, чи, може, вона запозичена з російської?

[Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009–](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

> Мультфильм – мультфільм.

Answer (score 1):

Згідно до [ЕСУМ](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_1989/EtSlUkrM_1989.pdf) (ст. 534 ПДФ) слово "мультфільм" (мультиплікаційний фільм) - **запозичене** з німецької мови, а якщо бути ще точнішим, то саме слово мультиплікація [походить](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F) з лат. "multiplicatio" — розмноження, збільшення, а фільм від англійського "film". Дивимося походження слова "мультиплікат":

[image]

На рахунок походження самого скорочення слова мультфільм - в Інтернеті немає ніяких офіційних або ж навіть неофіційних джерел, які могли дати хоча б інформацію, коли саме це скорочення з'явилося. Особисто я гадаю, що слово "мультфільм" виникло із розвитком мультиплікації на просторах СРСР (приблизно у 1936, коли було засновано першу кіностудію Союзмульфільму (тут ми бачимо, що це скорочення вже тоді вживалося в російській мові)). Але як розвивалася мультиплікація в Україні?

Мені вдалося знайти інформацію про книгу [Бориса Крижанівського "Мальоване кіно України"](http://uartlib.org/allbooks/istoriya-ukrayinskogo-mistetstva/boris-krizhanivskiy-malovane-kino-ukrayini-kniga-pro-multiplikatsiyu/), де ішлося, що в Україні засновником мультиплікації є [Левандовський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%92%27%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2_%D0%92%27%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). І справді, у 1927 він зняв **анімаційний фільм** "Казка про солом'яного бичка" (але як бачимо, це було зроблено на Одеській фабриці ВУФКУ, тобто за часів, коли значна частина України знаходилася під владою СРСР). І ось тут не зрозуміло, як тоді саме українці називали цей вид мистецтва - чи мальоване кіно, чи анімаційне кіно чи все ж таки мультиплікаційний фільм (який потім скоротили до "мультфільму").

Як бачимо, як і в російській так і в українській мовах були всі передумови для виникнення даного слова (бо не забуваймо, що воно утворилося від двох запозичених слів, які могли бути відомими як нашим мультиплікаторам, так і їхнім сусідам).

Comment: Анатолій, питання про мультфільм, а не мультиплікацію

Comment: Слово мультфільм - мультиплікаційний фільм... У вас виникли сумніви чи слово "фільм" запозичене?! Мені здається тут і так все зрозуміло, а от про походження слова "мультиплікація", яке складає першу частину слова мультфільм я написав докладніше. Чесно, я не розумію за що мінус, бо якщо вже й ставете його, то поясніть нормально, що саме вам не сподобалося.

Comment: Я так розумію, підтекст запитання — чи слово _мультфільм_ запозичене напряму з німецької, чи через російську (чи, може, власна комбінація чужих слів). Якщо розглядати запитання так, то різниця між _мультиплікаційний фільм_ і _мультфільм_ стає суттєвішою: наприклад, слова _мультиплікаційний_ і _фільм_ можуть виявитися давнішими запозиченнями з заходу, а _мультфільм_ — новішим запозиченням/калькою/утворенням часів СРСР. Але оскільки запитання це ніяк не пояснює, то я вважаю, що мінус Вам поставили дарма — Ваша відповідь чітко дає зрозуміти, що принаймні одна з частин слова є запозиченою.

Comment: А я не звертався до когось конкретного)
Просто, якщо стоїть мінус, то хочеться знати, що саме не так і, якщо є якась справді помилка у відповіді, я її обов'язково виправлю чи доповню відповідь.

Comment: @MariiaMatskevych, поясню свою думку. Мені здається, в цьому випадку запитання має бути вточнене. Бо формально воно правильне — Ви питаєте про _мультфільм_, але при швидкому прочитанні відповідач може не розуміти, що Ви питаєте **саме** про скорочення _мультфільм_, а не про слова в його основі.

Comment: @Анатолій, я попросив Марію Мацкевич відредагувати запитання (і частково відредагував сам). Тепер воно стало, мені здається, конкретнішим, але тепер, мені здається, мне несумісне з такою відповіддю.

Comment: А я в ЕСУМ бачу, що слово мультфільм незрозуміло звідки запозичене, а не з німецької (там є лише посилання на російську й болгарську). Мінус зняв, бо тут вже серйозна спроба розібратися. Давайте продовжимо.